# How do I reduce the double integral $\iint\limits_{x^2+y^2\leq1} f(\alpha x + \beta y +\gamma)dx\,dy$ to one integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I found this integral identity in a formula handbook (Integral and Series, Vol 1, Prudnikov):

$$ \iint\limits_{x^2+y^2\leq1} f(\alpha x + \beta y +\gamma)dx\,dy = 2\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{1-t^2}\, f \left(t\sqrt{\alpha^2 + \beta^2}+\gamma \right) dt$$

It is assumed that $\alpha>0$ and $\beta > 0$. How can I prove this identity? This is the first time I see this kind of identity and I don't know how to properly start the demonstration. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rotate the $xy$-axes such that the new coordinates are $(t,s)$ with
$$t= \frac {\alpha x +\beta y}{\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}}$$
and then integrate in $(t,s)$-coordinates as follows

\begin{align}
&\iint\limits_{x^2+y^2\leq1} f(\alpha x + \beta y +\gamma)\>dx\,dy \\
=& \iint\limits_{t^2+s^2\leq1} f \left(t\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2} +\gamma \right)ds\>dt\\
 =& \int_{-1}^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1-t^2}}^{\sqrt{1-t^2}} f \left( t\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2} +\gamma \right) ds\>dt\\
= & \>2\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{1-t^2}\, f \left(t\sqrt{\alpha^2 + \beta^2}+\gamma \right) dt
\end{align}